# Oracle SQL Query Help - Student Attendance

Tags: sql

I have the query below that pulls the daily attendance (period 1 through 10) for students enrolled in sports or activities in schools. I only want to see students with at least one absence in one of those periods, so if the attendance code for all periods is NULL they should not appear. I am not sure how to add that to the query. Can anyone help?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
      s.student_number AS "Student Number", 
      s.lastfirst AS "Student Name", 
      DECODE(s.grade_level,-1,'PK',0,'KG',s.grade_level) AS "Grade", 
      s.home_phone AS "Phone", 
      DECODE(s.schoolid,280050,'Kodiak High School',s.schoolid) AS "School",
      (SELECT DISTINCT co.course_name FROM ps.courses WHERE co.course_number=se.course_number AND se.course_number LIKE 'CLB%' OR se.course_number LIKE 'ACT%') AS "Course Name",
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='1') AS "Per. 1", 
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='2') AS "Per. 2", 
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='3') AS "Per. 3", 
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='4') AS "Per. 4", 
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='5') AS "Per. 5", 
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='6') AS "Per. 6", 
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='7') AS "Per. 7", 
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='8') AS "Adv", 
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='9') AS "Act", 
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='10') AS "Clb" 

      FROM attendance att 
      JOIN students s ON s.id=att.studentid 
      INNER JOIN cc ON s.ID=cc.studentid 
      INNER JOIN sections se ON cc.sectionid = se.id
      JOIN courses co ON co.course_number=se.COURSE_NUMBER

      WHERE att.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) 
      AND att.schoolid in '280050'
      AND s.enroll_status=0 
      AND cc.termid = 2700 
      AND se.course_number LIKE 'ACT%'OR se.course_number LIKE 'CLB%'

      ORDER BY s.lastfirst
```

Here is a sample of the data. I don't want to see the rows when all periods are NULL. Only if they have an absence code.[Data Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhnML.png)

Comment: Yikes! see: `DISTINCT is *usually* bad` at [Some Simple SQL Rules to Live By](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2006/03/14/9289.aspx) and/or 
[Why I Hate DISTINCT](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/markc/archive/2008/11/11/60752.aspx) & "decode" isn't a great thing to learn either, `case expressions` are generally preferred. You need a `group by` clause and a `having` clause so I regret to say it but "start fresh"

Comment: Could we see (using text, not an image) a sampling of data from table `pssis_attendance_meeting` add this into your question please. Sample of data from the other tables would also help if you want a comprehensive answer.

Comment: Formatting a table so it looks good in the question simply requires 4 spaces at the left of each row, or, use this button `{}` in the toolbar to do that for you. You can always look the the help link in the footnote for hints on how to use the site.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but I was not able to incorporate the query you posted into the query I already have so I am still trying to figure out how to show only students with absences that are enrolled in sports/activities. I just posted the question again but if you think is better I can create a whole new  question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly you are not understanding what I thought you would. Take what I have provided an **make a new query** which will look a bit like this:

```
SELECT
      s.*, att.* --  choose which columns you want, form these sources or other you can add to it
from students AS s
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                    studentid
                  , max(case when period_number='1'  then attcodes end) per1
                  , max(case when period_number='2'  then attcodes end) per2
                  , max(case when period_number='3'  then attcodes end) per3
                  , max(case when period_number='4'  then attcodes end) per4
                  , max(case when period_number='5'  then attcodes end) per5
                  , max(case when period_number='6'  then attcodes end) per6
                  , max(case when period_number='7'  then attcodes end) per7
                  , max(case when period_number='8'  then attcodes end) per8
                  , max(case when period_number='9'  then attcodes end) per9
                  , max(case when period_number='10' then attcodes end) per10
            FROM (
                  SELECT
                          attm.studentid
                        , attm.period_number
                        , listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) attcodes
                  FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm 
                  WHERE attm.att_date=to_date('14-Dec-2017') 
                  AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL 
                  GROUP BY
                          attm.studentid
                        , attm.period_number
                  ) d
            GROUP BY
                    studentid
      ) AS att on s.studentid = att.studentid
```

You choose the columns you want, form wherever you want, but if you use the subquery I have given you, using an INNER JOIN it will solve the "not null" issue.

Please tell me you now understand.

Comment: This is what my answer is supposed to lead you to. Create a NEW QUERY. Do not attempt to modify that existing query. Just add the extra columns you need. This will be my final comment on this question. If you keep asking for more I shall delete my answers. Sorry, but enough is enough in my view.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I understand what you are saying but for someone with very basic knowledge of SQL it is a little hard to get the results I want when I have to join so many tables. No need to get upset. I will try to figure it out if I can't I will post again and hopefully someone else will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I know very very little about the data you are dealing with, I would like to suggest this as a starting point:

```
SELECT
        studentid
      , max(case when period_number='1'  then attcodes end) per1
      , max(case when period_number='2'  then attcodes end) per2
      , max(case when period_number='3'  then attcodes end) per3
      , max(case when period_number='4'  then attcodes end) per4
      , max(case when period_number='5'  then attcodes end) per5
      , max(case when period_number='6'  then attcodes end) per6
      , max(case when period_number='7'  then attcodes end) per7
      , max(case when period_number='8'  then attcodes end) per8
      , max(case when period_number='9'  then attcodes end) per9
      , max(case when period_number='10' then attcodes end) per10
FROM (
      SELECT
              attm.studentid
            , attm.period_number
            , listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) attcodes
      FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm 
      WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) 
      AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL 
      GROUP BY
              attm.studentid
            , attm.period_number
      ) d
GROUP BY
        studentid
;
```

This will produce one row per student with 10 columns of attendance codes. I don't know why you would have multiple attendance codes for a single period, but I have continued with use of listagg() just in case you do.

In this query the logic removes any students that have no attendance codes registered for that day.

I hope this may help you arrive at an overall solution.

---

## edit

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23cdd/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE PSSIS_ATTENDANCE_MEETING
    (NAME varchar2(15), STUDENT_NUMBER int
     , CURRENT_GRADE_LEVEL int
     , CURRENT_SCHOOL_ABBREVIATION varchar2(3)
     , GENDER varchar2(1)
     , ETHNICITY_NAME varchar2(4), ETHNICITY_CODE int
     , SPECIAL_ED_STUDENT varchar2(2), ID int, STUDENTID int, SCHOOLID int
     , ATT_DATE timestamp, ATTENDANCE_CODEID int, ATT_CODE varchar2(3)
     , ATT_MODE_CODE varchar2(15), ATT_INTERVAL int, CALENDAR_DAYID int
     , CCID int, ATT_COMMENT int, CC_SCHOOLID int, DROPPED int, PERIODID int
     , PERIOD_ABBREVIATION varchar2(2), PERIOD_NUMBER int, SECTIONID int
     , SECTION_NUMBER int, PROGRAMID int, PROGRAM_NAME int, TRACK_A int
     , TRACK_B int, TRACK_C int, TRACK_D int, TRACK_E int, TRACK_F int
     , INSESSION int, COUNT_FOR_ADA int, PRESENCE_STATUS_CD varchar2(6)
     , CYCLE_DAY_ID int, CYCLE_DAY_ABBREVIATION varchar2(2), TOTAL_MINUTES int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO PSSIS_ATTENDANCE_MEETING (NAME, STUDENT_NUMBER, CURRENT_GRADE_LEVEL, CURRENT_SCHOOL_ABBREVIATION, GENDER, ETHNICITY_NAME, ETHNICITY_CODE, SPECIAL_ED_STUDENT, ID, STUDENTID, SCHOOLID, ATT_DATE, ATTENDANCE_CODEID, ATT_CODE, ATT_MODE_CODE, ATT_INTERVAL, CALENDAR_DAYID, CCID, ATT_COMMENT, CC_SCHOOLID, DROPPED, PERIODID, PERIOD_ABBREVIATION, PERIOD_NUMBER, SECTIONID, SECTION_NUMBER, PROGRAMID, PROGRAM_NAME, TRACK_A, TRACK_B, TRACK_C, TRACK_D, TRACK_E, TRACK_F, INSESSION, COUNT_FOR_ADA, PRESENCE_STATUS_CD, CYCLE_DAY_ID, CYCLE_DAY_ABBREVIATION,TOTAL_MINUTES)
         VALUES ('used_by_already', 999999, 1, 'OHS', 'F', NULL, 6, 'No', 7240947, 40576, 280100, '14-Dec-2017 12:00:00 AM', 4345, 'EXA', 'ATT_ModeMeeting', 0, 97488, 790700, NULL, 280100, 0, 5731, 'AM', 1, 66373, 1, 0, NULL, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'Absent', 3214, 'TH', 0)
    INTO PSSIS_ATTENDANCE_MEETING (NAME, STUDENT_NUMBER, CURRENT_GRADE_LEVEL, CURRENT_SCHOOL_ABBREVIATION, GENDER, ETHNICITY_NAME, ETHNICITY_CODE, SPECIAL_ED_STUDENT, ID, STUDENTID, SCHOOLID, ATT_DATE, ATTENDANCE_CODEID, ATT_CODE, ATT_MODE_CODE, ATT_INTERVAL, CALENDAR_DAYID, CCID, ATT_COMMENT, CC_SCHOOLID, DROPPED, PERIODID, PERIOD_ABBREVIATION, PERIOD_NUMBER, SECTIONID, SECTION_NUMBER, PROGRAMID, PROGRAM_NAME, TRACK_A, TRACK_B, TRACK_C, TRACK_D, TRACK_E, TRACK_F, INSESSION, COUNT_FOR_ADA, PRESENCE_STATUS_CD, CYCLE_DAY_ID, CYCLE_DAY_ABBREVIATION,TOTAL_MINUTES)
         VALUES ('used_by_already', 999999, 1, 'OHS', 'F', NULL, 6, 'No', 7240948
                 , 40576, 280100, '14-Dec-2017 12:00:00 AM', 4345
                 , 'EXA', 'ATT_ModeMeeting', 0, 97488, 790696, NULL
                 , 280100, 0, 5732, 'PM', 2, 66427, 1, 0, NULL
                 , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'Absent', 3214, 'TH'
                 , 0)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
      SELECT
              attm.studentid
            , attm.period_number
            , listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) attcodes
      FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm 
      WHERE attm.att_date=to_date('14-Dec-2017') 
      AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL 
      GROUP BY
              attm.studentid
            , attm.period_number
;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23cdd/2/0)**:

```
| STUDENTID | PERIOD_NUMBER | ATTCODES |
|-----------|---------------|----------|
|     40576 |             1 |      EXA |
|     40576 |             2 |      EXA |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT
        studentid
      , max(case when period_number='1'  then attcodes end) per1
      , max(case when period_number='2'  then attcodes end) per2
      , max(case when period_number='3'  then attcodes end) per3
      , max(case when period_number='4'  then attcodes end) per4
      , max(case when period_number='5'  then attcodes end) per5
      , max(case when period_number='6'  then attcodes end) per6
      , max(case when period_number='7'  then attcodes end) per7
      , max(case when period_number='8'  then attcodes end) per8
      , max(case when period_number='9'  then attcodes end) per9
      , max(case when period_number='10' then attcodes end) per10
FROM (
      SELECT
              attm.studentid
            , attm.period_number
            , listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) attcodes
      FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm 
      WHERE attm.att_date=to_date('14-Dec-2017') 
      AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL 
      GROUP BY
              attm.studentid
            , attm.period_number
      ) d
GROUP BY
        studentid
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23cdd/2/1)**:

```
| STUDENTID | PER1 | PER2 |   PER3 |   PER4 |   PER5 |   PER6 |   PER7 |   PER8 |   PER9 |  PER10 |
|-----------|------|------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|     40576 |  EXA |  EXA | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Some students are enrolled in more than one sport/activity that is why we ave multiple rows for some students. We send this report to each coach for the student attendance for the day.

Comment: I was trying to group the result by sport/activity course name but was also not successful on that. When I add GROUP BY COURSE NAME I get a error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Debora, it is so hard to help when we have no data to look at. That is why I asked if I could see some data earlier. Which table(s) give you the `attendance to course` reference? Is it in `pssis_attendance_meeting`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! These tables have so many fields that is hard to attach here. What is the easiest way to share a sample of all of these tables here?

Comment: small text tables, added into your question (do not try to use comments for this). just a few rows is usually all that is needed. scrub anything private. This link https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ allows copy/paste of excel to fixed table. dates should be yyyy-mm-dd if possible

Comment: I think I am already getting the results I need but I just wanted to show only records where attm.att_code IS NOT NULL for all periods and then group them by the course name.

Comment: the code above should only list students with non-null attendance for whole day, **IF the attendance data really is NULL** and not some other "value".

Comment: can you please provide data from at least `pssis_attendance_meeting` honestly, the best way forward

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The query above works great but I am having a hard time join that query to the query I already have. Do you think you can help me?

Comment: Don't over complicate THIS question, **ask another question**. Much better to take things one problem at a time. In that new question provide the query you are using, and learn how to format tables in your question, it is v.easy (4 spaces on the left for each row).

Comment: I used the link you gave me to format the table but when I paste here the formatting is gone.

Comment: 4 spaces to the left of every row.... or use the `{}` button in the toolbar which does that for you. or use help in the footnote. You can see that I do it.... last time I will post this advice, 3rd time now

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your patience! My query below works to pull the attendance for all periods for students enrolled in activities/sports. Now I am trying to only show records when there's an absence in one or more periods. I tried adding attm.att_code IS NOT NULL but I could not find a way to do that for all periods so obviously did not work. I can get multiple rows for students that are enrolled in more than one sport/activity but the attendance will be the same in both rows.

I also wanted to group the attendance by sports/activity but when I add GROUP BY co.course_name at the end of query it doesn't work either.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      s.student_number AS "Student Number", 
      s.lastfirst AS "Student Name", 
      DECODE(s.grade_level,-1,'PK',0,'KG',s.grade_level) AS "Grade", 
      s.home_phone AS "Phone", 
      DECODE(s.schoolid,280050,'Kodiak High School',s.schoolid) AS "School",
      (SELECT DISTINCT co.course_name FROM ps.courses WHERE co.course_number=se.course_number AND se.course_number LIKE 'CLB%' OR se.course_number LIKE 'ACT%') AS "Course",
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='1') AS "Per. 1", 
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='2') AS "Per. 2", 
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='3') AS "Per. 3", 
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='4') AS "Per. 4", 
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='5') AS "Per. 5", 
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='6') AS "Per. 6", 
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='7') AS "Per. 7", 
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='8') AS "Adv", 
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='9') AS "Act", 
      (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='10') AS "Clb" 

      FROM attendance att
      JOIN students s ON s.id=att.studentid
      INNER JOIN cc ON s.ID=cc.studentid 
      INNER JOIN sections se ON cc.sectionid = se.id
      JOIN courses co ON co.course_number=se.COURSE_NUMBER

      WHERE att.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) 
      AND att.schoolid in '280050'
      AND s.enroll_status=0 
      AND cc.termid = 2700 
      AND se.course_number LIKE 'ACT%'OR se.course_number LIKE 'CLB%'


      ORDER BY s.lastfirst
```

Comment: This site is NOT a "conversation thread".... it is a question then answer site.  Repeating you query isn't useful. and I have provided an answer **which, if you implement it,** will not not only solve the NOT NULL but will improve efficiency. Short of writing the whole thing for you (unpaid) what more do you expect of me?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
         s.student_number AS "Student Number"
       , s.lastfirst AS "Student Name"
       , DECODE(s.grade_level, - 1, 'PK', 0, 'KG', s.grade_level) AS "Grade"
       , s.home_phone AS "Phone"
       , DECODE(s.schoolid, 280050, 'Kodiak High School', s.schoolid) AS "School"
       , att.*
FROM (
            SELECT
                    studentid
                  , max(case when period_number='1'  then attcodes end) per1
                  , max(case when period_number='2'  then attcodes end) per2
                  , max(case when period_number='3'  then attcodes end) per3
                  , max(case when period_number='4'  then attcodes end) per4
                  , max(case when period_number='5'  then attcodes end) per5
                  , max(case when period_number='6'  then attcodes end) per6
                  , max(case when period_number='7'  then attcodes end) per7
                  , max(case when period_number='8'  then attcodes end) per8
                  , max(case when period_number='9'  then attcodes end) per9
                  , max(case when period_number='10' then attcodes end) per10
            FROM (
                  SELECT
                          attm.studentid
                        , attm.period_number
                        , listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) attcodes
                  FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm 
                  WHERE attm.att_date=trunc(sysdate)
                  AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL 
                  AND attm.schoolid IN '280050'
                  GROUP BY
                          attm.studentid
                        , attm.period_number
                  ) d
            GROUP BY
                    studentid
     ) att
INNER JOIN students s ON s.id = att.studentid
INNER JOIN cc ON s.ID = cc.studentid
INNER JOIN sections se ON cc.sectionid = se.id
INNER JOIN courses co ON co.course_number = se.COURSE_NUMBER
WHERE s.enroll_status = 0 AND cc.termid = 2700 AND se.course_number LIKE 'ACT%' OR se.course_number LIKE 'CLB%'
ORDER BY s.lastfirst
```